# Xfce4 sound can't be un-muted

Tags: sound, 13.10, xfce, mute

I have no sound on Xfce4. When I mute sound on Xfce (Or login to Xfce with the sound muted from the last shutdown), un-muting the sound doesn't actually un-mute all the sound outputs. It only un-mutes the **master** level, but not the **speaker** nor the **headphone** levels.

In the attached picture, when I mute\un-mute the sound, only the **master** level is responding.

My laptop is a **Dell Inspiron SE 7520**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this issue, too. Try the `Switches` tab in `xfce4-mixer` and make sure that all the relevant switches there are enabled.

Comment: As I told you in the other question, I only installed xfce4 this time. This problem doesn't exist anymore ! Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Did you try to first `mute` and then `unmute`? This is when it doesn't work properly on my system.

Comment: Sure, i tried muting and unmuting and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was able to fix it by:

1. Right-click the volume control in the taskbar
2. Select **Properties** and change the **Sound Card** in the drop down to *Playback: Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo (PulseAudio Mixer)*.

After doing that the unmute worked for all the sound outputs.